# cmake issue trying to generate configuration for glfw on windows

Tags: c, cmake, glfw

im trying to generate the configuration for glfw after cloning the source from https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git .  I get an error only on  windows (on ubuntu linux i have no issue) .  I suspect an issue with my CMake but im not sure.

When I run CMake from the root directory of glfw  I get the following error using Cmake 2.8

```
C:\temp\glfw-master>cmake .
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Using WGL for context creation
CMake Error at examples/CMakeLists.txt:16 (include_directories):
include_directories given empty-string as include directory.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I then tried upgrading to CMake latest 3.0.1 , I still get the error but with a little more info :

```
$ cmake .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 11 2012
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.61030.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 11 2012
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 11 2012 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Using WGL for context creation
CMake Error at examples/CMakeLists.txt:16 (include_directories):
  include_directories given empty-string as include directory.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/temp/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/temp/glfw/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

If I check the `CMakeError.log` it seems to mention missing pthreads (which doesnt make sense to me since this is windows and probably `pthreads.h` should only be used on posix based OSs)

```
CheckIncludeFiles.c
CheckIncludeFiles.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h'
: No such file or directory [C:\temp\glfw\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec38
59330081.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\temp\glfw\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec38593300
81.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\temp\glfw\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3859330081.vcxproj" (default t
arget) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  CheckIncludeFiles.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.
h': No such file or directory [C:\temp\glfw\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec
3859330081.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Could anyone shed light on what I might have missed? I tried posting this question in glfw irc and discussion forum but i think its not very active and i am under the gun to get this running.  It could also be that i am not getting an answer there because its more related to CMake and my configuration than it is glfw per se.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the actual issue (referring to `include_directories` given empty string) is `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR` is not properly set, which should come from `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)`. Do you have the proper OpenGL headers installed?

Comment: Yes, I have the OpenGL headers installed. What made you suspect that though ? In the CMake output above it says : `-- Found OpenGL: opengl32`

Comment: I took a look at line 16 of `examples/CMakeLists.txt` in the git repo you linked, and that's what the line was: `include_directories("${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")`

Comment: hmm, you are right I see that now too.  Checking now if i can explicitly pass that to CMake. OpengGL headers are installed, and a lot of my source does find the GL includes in : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\gl

Comment: i simply commented that line out that checks for opengl include dir.  Not really sure why its not finding the opengl headers, tried it on two machines now with the same result.  Thanks for the help

Comment: This was fixed in GLFW 3.0.4.